# Why I can't run my bot command (discord.py)?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have some problem when I try to create a bot 
Here is a part of my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    await client.process_commands(message)
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    general_channel = client.get_channel(874180398475804695)

    await general_channel.send('I am ready',delete_after=10)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if any(word in message.content for word in rude_word):
        await message.reply('Hey man, that word is not allowed here .',delete_after=2)
        await message.delete()

@client.command(name='ping')
async def ping(message):
    await message.reply('pong')
```

When I type command, the bot does not work.
BUT, if I remove the part of:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if any(word in message.content for word in rude_word):
        await message.reply('Hey man, that word is not allowed here .',delete_after=2)
        await message.delete()
```

The command works again.
Another situation, I remove :

```
@client.command(name='ping')
async def ping(message):
    await message.reply('pong')
```

The bot still can works(delete message). However, when I combine these two, the `@client.command` doesn't works. I have try my best to figure it out but still have no idea. What can I do to let the commands work?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with on_message. You need to add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of `on_message` as mentioned [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) in the `discord.py` FAQ.

Comment: I use `@client.listen('on_message')`, and now I fix my problem.